# Domain of Predicate

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Exercise from the book A Transition to Advanced Mathematics:

For every positive real number $x$, there is a positive real number $y$ with the property that if $y<x$, then for all positive real numbers $z$, $yz\geq z$.

I'm totally fine with the above exercise. However, i have a confusion over the Domain of the predicate variable in the exercise below.

Edited Exercise:

For every positive real number $x$, there is a positive real number $y<x$ with the property that for every positive real number $z$, $yz\geq z$.

Is a) or b) the domain of $y$?

a) $y\in \{y\in \mathbb{R^+} : y<x\}$

b) $y\in \mathbb{R^+}$ and $P(x,y): y<x$ is a property.

Are they different and how are they different?

What is the difference between the original exercise and the edited exercise in the case that $y$ satisfies the condition $y<x$?

I have tried using both a) and b) in forming the negation of the original statement to prove that the original statement is false. a) turns out well but b) gives me a very weird statement.

Comment: The *domain* is the set of "positive real numbers" $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: In the negation of the statement, i would take the negation of $P(x,y)$, which is $y\geq x$ and this results in a weird statement.

Comment: $\forall x \in \mathbb R^+ \ \exists y \in \mathbb R^+ \ (y < x \to \forall z \in \mathbb R^ \ (yz \ge z))$

Comment: How about that for the edited exercise? i forgot to insert that in the original post, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In logic you can't make your domain dependent on some variable, as you seem to be trying to do in b): all variables are quantified over the same domain.

Now, if you specify that the doamin is $\mathbb{R}^+$, then your statement can be symbolized as such:

$\forall x \ \exists y \ (y < x \rightarrow \forall z \ yz \ge z)$

If your domain is larger than that, say all real numbers  $\mathbb{R}$, then you can write:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \exists y \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ (y < x \rightarrow \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ yz \ge z)$

though this is really just shorthand for:

$\forall x ( x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \exists y (y \in \mathbb{R}^+ \land (y < x \rightarrow \forall z (z \in \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow yz \ge z)))$

This statement is true, since for any $x$, you can simply pick $y=x$, making $y<x$ false, and thus the whole conditional true.

For your edited exercise, you get:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \exists y \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ (y < x \land \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ yz \ge z)$

This statement is false, since if $x < 1$, then that means $y < 1$, and then $yz < z$.

The negation of this is:

$\neg \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \exists y \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ (y < x \land \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ yz \ge z)$

which is equivalent to:

$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ (y \ge x \lor \exists z \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ yz < z)$

This statement is true, since you can just pick $x =1 $, meaning that for any $y \ge 1$ you have $y \ge x$, and for $y<1$ you have $yz < z$, so for any $y$, one of the disjuncts will hold.

Comment: Can you write the statement of the edited exercise in symbol form? I have no issue with the original exercise.

Comment: @LittleRookie OK, give me a sec ...

Comment: The negation of the edited exercise will give a very strange statement that cannot be proved to be true. Can you show the negation of the statement?

Comment: Negation of $y<x$ is $y\geq x$. you wrote $x\leq y$. Now, the negation form is false. Which means the original statement is true, but the original statement is obviously false.

Comment: @LittleRookie Whoops! editing ....

Comment: Now, the negation form is false. Which means the original statement is true, but the original statement is obviously false. I'm confused.

Comment: @LittleRookie I'll add my thoughts to the post ...

Comment: Thanks. Now im thinking maybe the exercise i had was typed wrongly. The suggested solution for the edited exercise is actually based on the negation of the original exercise. =/